# Do analytical results always "trump" numerical ones?

Tags: mathematical-physics, computational-physics, soft-question

Suppose I have a system that can be described by some differential equation(s). If I can manage to write down a proper analytical solution to it, but which I can't quite replicate numerically, whether for technical reasons or otherwise, can I still claim to have "solved the problem" ? Specifically in the context of mathematical physics / GR .

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "technical reasons or otherwise". If your analytical solution is correct, it should be replicable numerically but for technical reasons. What is the "otherwise"?

Comment: This is a hypothetical question, but I can imagine scenarios where one cannot carry out the numerical solution, maybe because they simply lack the technical skills, the equations are unstable / stiff, or the numerical results simply differ from the analytical ones.

Comment: All of those are technical reasons except for the last one where you suggest that a numerical result might simply differ from the analytic one. Well, it can't unless one of them is wrong.

Answer (score 6):

"The purpose of (scientific) computing is insight, not numbers". -- Richard Hamming

When solving a physics problem, at the end of the day what matters is whether you are able to get an interesting insight into the physical system. There are cases when having an exact, analytical solution is much less useful than a good approximation, because the exact solution is written in terms of special functions that obscure a simple trend. Numerical solutions are similarly tricky; for example, in the context of gravitational waves, the field absolutely relies on having high-quality numerical simulations of the merger of binary black holes and neutron stars. However, any one simulation by itself is not particularly helpful for estimating the parameters of real-world events, what really matters is having enough simulations that other methods can interpolate between them so one can infer how features of the waveform depend on the parameters.

Which is to say, there aren't hard or fast rules about what constitutes solving a physics problem. It very much depends on the context.

Of course, you want to be able to *test* your solution, in order to validate it. A very good way to test your solution is to use two different methods (the more different the methods, the better) to arrive at the solution, and show the solutions obtained with the different methods agree. Showing that the analytical formula agrees with a numerical simulation can therefore be a very powerful check.

If the two solutions disagree, it means you've made a mistake in at least one of the two methods (or that you've underestimated the uncertainty in them). However, this doesn't necessarily mean you need to fix the broken method, because there are other tests you can do, and usually in real life you have to consider what option is going to be the best use of your time. It may be that having a numerical and an analytic solution is the easiest test, but it may also be that a different series of tests is just as convincing and more efficient (in fact it's pretty rare in practice to find a situation where it's useful or even possible to obtain both a numerical solution and an exact analytic solution, except as a calibration/test case for a new method). For an analytic solution, you could for instance try plugging the formula into the differential equation and show explicitly that the differential equation is satisfied; you could take limits of the solution and show it reproduces known special cases; you could find a friend and both derive the analytic solution without talking to each other and compare notes at the end. For a numerical solution, you can test the convergence of the simulation by doing the simulation on different resolutions; you can check how well any exactly known properties of the solutions hold (for example, is energy conserved); you can check against known limits of the solution; you could implement different numerical schemes (especially ones with different sources of numerical error) and compare them.

Answer (score 3):

This seems a bit too vague to answer. I can see two scenarios:

1. Your equations describe accurately the system you want to analyze (and your solution is the correct one). In this case, the failure of a numerical verification is presumably related to a too slow convergence of the numerical algorithm, too low precision, etc. In such a case, your theoretical result of course solves the problem.
2. Your equations actually model the system only in some ideal limit. In this case, it is quite possible that the numerical simulation works as intended, but that the differences in behavior are linked to the ideal assumptions not being satisfied for the simulated system. When this occurs, the numerical results might be actually more relevant for the description of the system you are interested in. Let me give two examples in a different context I am familiar with, (mathematical) equilibrium statistical mechanics:

   - In two-dimensional systems, a continuous symmetry cannot be spontaneously broken (Mermin-Wagner theorem). Here the assumption is that the system is infinite (thermodynamic limit). However, even extremely large (but finite) systems will exhibit an ordered phase at low temperatures, as will the numerical simulations. In that case, the latter might be very relevant.
   - A second example would be systems that take a huge amount of time to reach their true equilibrium (say, spin glasses for instance). In that case, the assumption that the true equilibrium has been reached (the infinite-time limit), which underlies the exact solution, might not be relevant for the actual system and your numerical simulations might turn out to be more relevant...

So, I'd say that it is not possible to answer in general without knowing more about the specificities of your problem. And even determining which of the two situations above occurs in a particular case might not be trivial.